# How to view reciprocal differences more easily

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

During my analysis class I have encountered expressions like $\left|\frac{1}{l} - \frac{1}{k}\right| < \text{ some bound }$ multiple times, where we deduce something regarding the values of the positive integers $l$ and $k$. My intuition regarding the reciprocals is limited, and most of the time I would like to expand the fractions to have a common denominator even if it does more harm than good. So, give some $\epsilon > 0$, what would you infer about $l, k$ in the inequality $\left|\frac{1}{l} - \frac{1}{k}\right| < \epsilon $?

Comment: Are you trying to infer $l,k$ are close together knowing the same is true of $l^{-1},k^{-1}$?

Comment: @Ian For example that, or if $l$ and $k$ represent values from some sequence, then for which indices onwards does this inequality hold.